# From IdentityServer3 successful login, how to automatically call WebAPi (MVC 5 Framework 4.8), without the physical click of the Call API button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, client, identityserver3

I've just started trying to set up IdentityServer3 on MVC5 app (latest framework).
The demo has a button to call the API, but I want to if the login is successful, automatically call the js function which does an ajax call back to my api.
The manager class has

```
.signinpopup()
```

and

```
.catch(function(error) { ..}
```

but does not support

```
.success(function(){…}
```

Is there some way of doing it from js , or is that handled by the server?, possibly in it's Client settings, maybe RedirectUris ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it, is once the login succeeds and writes the token into a div element, hide the div element and use the jquery onchange event to call the function to call the API.